# bash - How to replace line feeds in a variable?

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace

Here is my script:

```
my_var="foo
bar
baz"

echo ${my_var//\n/\\n}
```

I want to replace all line feeds with `\\n`.

However here is what I have:

```
foo bar baz
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this does what you want:

```
$ echo "${my_var//$'\n'/\\n}"
foo\nbar\nbaz
```

There are two important things to note:

1. Quote your variables! Your expansion wasn't making any replacements but the whitespace in the variable was being squashed due to word-splitting. `echo` prints each of its arguments separated by a single space.
2. Use `$'\n'` for a C-style string, to get a newline character in the *search* part of the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$ echo "${my_var//      
/\\n}"
foo\nbar\nbaz
```

Relevant finding: To insert a literal newline anywhere in a command without running it you can press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd>.